# inserir a licença no SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Bom dia Senhores(as)

Fiz a instalação do SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) e após comprei a licença, porém não consigo achar um tutorial ou algo que me ajuda a inserir a licença e validar no SQL Server, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Eis passo a passo obtido no documento “[SQL Server on Linux Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-faq?view=sql-server-ver15#licensing)”:

When you **run mssql-conf setup** you are presented with the following options:

Choose an edition of SQL Server:

1. Evaluation (free, no production use rights, 180-day limit)
2. Developer (free, no production use rights)
3. Express (free)
4. Web (PAID)
5. Standard (PAID)
6. Enterprise (PAID)
7. Enterprise Core (PAID)
8. I bought a license through a retail sales channel and have a product key to enter.

If you have obtained your license through volume licensing as part of an Enterprise Agreement or through your MSDN subscription, you need to select options 4 through 7. This step does not ask you to enter the license, but you must have previously purchased the appropriate license for your configuration. If you have purchased Standard edition through a retail channel, select option 8. This option does prompt you to enter a key.

---

As instruções gerais para instalação do SQL Server em distribuição GNU/Linux estão no documento “[Installation guidance for SQL Server on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15)”.

Comment: Mas se eu tiver a instalação feita do `5. Standard (PAID)` e posteriormente executar `mssql-conf setup` não terei duplicação de instalação?
Como eu comprei a licença depois da instalação, achei que tinha outra forma de fazer isso sem ser pelo `mssql-conf setup`